# How to use AnimatedGrid

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am trying to turn this gridview into an animated grid list, I've been struggling on it for a bit now, I just kind of want some guidance at this point. I am super new to flutter, like within a month or so, and so far progress has been pretty steady but when i got to animated lists for some reason I couldn't quite wrap my head around them. I would appreciate a simple explanation if it wouldn't be too much trouble

basically, I want for when I add to this list of dynamic widgets which then generates a material button in this gridview, for the new material button to have an animation upon being generated.

So far, whenever I tried to add either an AnimatedGrid widget or some sort of animation controller, I could never get the animation to play, and also, something which im split on being a separate issue and solution entirely is that the page only updates when I move away from the page to another navigation destination and then go back, to where the material button has appeared where I wanted it to, without any animation.

The updating problem is probably just due to my inexperience, but i would appreciate some guidance there as well.

here is the relevant code

```
String groupName = '';
final groupNameList = <String>[];
List<Widget> _dynamicWidgets = [];
```

...

```
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 5,
              ),
              itemCount: groupNameList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: ((context) => _dynamicWidgets[index]),
```

...

```
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 96, 139, 110),
                              hoverColor:
                                  const Color.fromARGB(255, 146, 206, 183),
                              child: const Text(
                                "Create Group",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                groupName = myController.text;
                                groupNameList.insert(0, groupName);
                                myController.clear();
                                _dynamicWidgets.insert(
                                    0, PageOfGroup(groupName: groupName));
```

...

```
class PageOfGroup extends StatefulWidget {
  final String groupName;
  const PageOfGroup({Key? key, required this.groupName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PageOfGroup> createState() => _PageOfGroupState();
}

class _PageOfGroupState extends State<PageOfGroup> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.groupName),
    ));
  }
}
```